# Add SQL Script inside of Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

Just wondering how i could add a sql script inside of a powershell script.
Right now I have a script that gets this sql file and run for each database. I was wondering if I could include this sql script inside of my powershell . I am planning to automate my powershell script to run daily.

Here is what i have at the moment

```
$out = foreach ($SERVER in $SERVERS) { 
 $InvokeParams = @{
  Server = $SERVER 
  Database = 'test database'
  Username = 'username'
  Password = 'password'
  InputFile = 'C:user\test.sql'
    QueryTimeout = 120 #avoid query to break
 }
```

Goal: Try to implement sql code inside of INPUTFILE instead of calling/giving a path for a sql file

Goal:

```
 InputFile = SQL SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only give an example since I don't know the contents of the sql script.

```
$out = foreach ($SERVER in $SERVERS) { 
 $InvokeParams = @{
  Server = $SERVER 
  Database = 'test database'
  Username = 'username'
  Password = 'password'
  Query = "Select Column1,Column2 from Table"
  QueryTimeout = 120 #avoid query to break
 }
 Invoke-Sqlcmd @InvokeParams
}
```

You would just need to add your query to the `Query` key in your `$InvokeParams` hash table. If you want to keep your hash table neater, you can always type the query as a string and set it to another variable. Then use `Query = $variable` in your hash table. If the query is long (multi-lined) and has other quotes in it, you can use a here-string (`@''@` or `@""@`) for simplification.

```
$Query = @'
USE Database
Select Table1.Column1,Table1.Column2,Table2.Column1
FROM Table1
JOIN Column1 ON Table2.Column1=Table1.Column1
GO
'@
$out = foreach ($SERVER in $SERVERS) { 
 $InvokeParams = @{
  Server = $SERVER 
  Database = 'test database'
  Username = 'username'
  Password = 'password'
  Query = $Query
  QueryTimeout = 120 #avoid query to break
 }
 Invoke-Sqlcmd @InvokeParams
}
```